# How to know, libxslt support EXSLT or not

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, libxml2, libxslt

I am on MacOSX 10.7, and having libxml2  version as i can see from libxml2/xmlversion.h is

## define LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION "2.7.3"

that means 2.7.3

My application also using xslt, for so it has libxslt processor, which comes along with the libxml2

some of the file may contains math function, something like this,

```
 <xsl:variable name="angle"
          select="math:atan2(30, 30)
              - math:atan2(30, 30)"/>
```

going through site http://www.exslt.org/howto.html it says, xslt processor should support EXSLT Function,

does anyone has any idea, how i can confirm it ?

Answer (score 0):

Some how i got it fixed,below are steps, 
1 -- I had to install libxml2 , and remove reference of libxml2 which was available through SDK, 
2 -- Compile libxslt too , and don't include which is there in the SDK, 
3 -- In the source code before applying style sheet call anyone of these function

```
EXSLTPUBFUN void EXSLTCALL exsltMathRegister (void);
EXSLTPUBFUN void EXSLTCALL exsltSetsRegister (void);
EXSLTPUBFUN void EXSLTCALL exsltFuncRegister (void);
EXSLTPUBFUN void EXSLTCALL exsltStrRegister (void);
EXSLTPUBFUN void EXSLTCALL exsltDateRegister (void);
EXSLTPUBFUN void EXSLTCALL exsltSaxonRegister (void);
EXSLTPUBFUN void EXSLTCALL exsltDynRegister(void);
```

4 -- you might need to change the XSL file to include the Name space for math and to import it

```
 xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
  xmlns:jDouble="java.lang.Double"
  exclude-result-prefixes="v math"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.0">
    <xsl:import href="math.xsl" />
```

Thanks for looking at it.